# Understanding try catch finally with return and value that it returns

Tags: java, return, return-value, try-catch-finally

I have the following piece of code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(returnString());
}
private static String returnString(){
    try {
        System.out.println("Executing try");
        return "Return try value";
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Executing Catch");
        return "Return catch value";
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Executing finally");
        return "Return finally value";
    }
}
```

The output for this is

```
Executing try
Executing finally
Return finally value
```

If I change my finally block to not return anything like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(returnString());
}
private static String returnString(){
    try {
        System.out.println("Executing try");
        return "Return try value";
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Executing Catch");
        return "Return catch value";
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Executing finally");
    }
}
```

Then the output is

```
Executing try
Executing finally
Return try value
```

Now I understand that finally is always executed except if we call system.exit(0); called or the JVM crashes.
What I'm not able to understand is why the return value has changed ? I would still expect it to return the value of the try block. 
Can anyone explain why the finally value is take into consideration and not the return value from the try block ?

**Please refrain from answering because finally is executed even if there is an return in try block ... or finally doesn't execute only if there is a system.exit(0); called or the JVM crashes. as I know that.**

### ## EDIT :

(As per [Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141081/dirk) comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26658946/1085186))

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(returnString());
}
private static String returnString(){
    try {
        System.out.println("Executing try");
        return printString("Return try value");
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Executing Catch");
        return printString("Return catch value");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Executing finally");
        return printString("Return finally value");
    }
}

private static String printString(String str){
    System.out.println(str);
    return str;
}
```

Output:

```
Executing try
Return try value
Executing finally
Return finally value
Return finally value
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2

Comment: Because, by definition, the finally clause is executed whenever you exit the try block.  System.exit(0) doesn't look like an exit to the compiler, and it throws no exception, so there's no way for finally to get control.  Likewise if the JVM crashes, without an exception being thrown within the try block.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just before returning from the main block, the JVM has to make sure the `finally` block is executed, so it does that. The idea is to execute the `finally` block and then come back and execute the `return` statement from the main block. But if you have a `return` statement in the `finally` block, then it will be executed when the `finally` block is executed... which means that control never returns to the main block to complete the `return` statement.

1. The JVM encounters the `return` statement in the main block. It pauses execution of the main block and checks for a `finally` clause.
2. It executes the `finally` clause in its entirety, including its `return` statement.
3. It never thus gets to complete the `try` block.

Note, however, that the `try` block's `return` expression *is evaluated* and then discarded. This is important if it has side effects. So if your main block has `return i++` then this will have no effect on the return value but `i` will still get incremented. (Thanks to [Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141081/dirk) for pointing this out.)

Comment: The expression *is* evaluated (and in particular, side effects will happen). But it's value will then be discarded (and overridden by the one of the `finally` clause)

Answer (score 2):

**If you have return in finally, that's the final return.**

That is not surprising. It is actual behavior. Returning value decided at `finally` block.

If you are not returning anything in finally then the *previous value of going to be return value* is the returning value (in your case, the try block value).

Regardless of what you are doing in `try`, the finally block always executes even though you return from your try  block (If you have return in finally, that's the final return).

From [`finally`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) docs

> The runtime system always executes the statements within the finally block **regardless** of what **happens** within the try block. So it's the perfect place to perform cleanup.

Note: finally designed to cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the code:

```
try {
  if (foo()) return 1;
} catch (Exception e){
  if (goo()) return 2;
} finally {
  if (moo()) return 3;
}
```

will rewritten by the compiler into:

```
try {
  if (foo())
  {
    if (moo()) return 3;  // Finally code executed before return
    return 1;
  }
} catch (Exception e){
  if (goo())
  {
    if (moo()) return 3;  // Finally code executed before return
    return 2;
  }
} catch (Throwable e){
  if (moo()) return 3;   // Finally code executed before re-throw
  throw e;
}
if (moo()) return 3;    // Finally code executed before leaving block
```

Basically, the compiler will duplicate the code in the `finally` block exactly once in every execution path that would cause code execution to leave the guarded block, whether via `return`, `throw`, or fall-through.  Note that while some languages disallow a `return` *within* a `finally` block, Java does not; if a `finally` block is executed as a consequence of an exception, however, a `return` within the block may cause the exception to get silently abandoned (look at the code above marked "Finally code executed before re-throw"; if the `return 3;` executes, the re-throw will get skipped).