# Will the 'finally' block fire even after a Junit test throws an Assertion Error from with in 'try' block?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, try-finally

Will the `writer.close()` method inside the `finally { }` block run on an Junit Assertion Error?

Assume the following code:

```
@Test 
public void testWriter() {

   try {
        writer.open();

        final List<MyBean> myBeans = new ArrayList<ProfileBean>();

        /** Add 2 beans to the myBeans List here. **/

        final int beansWritten = writer.writeBeans(myBeans);

        // Say this assertion error below is triggered
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("Wrong number of beans written.", -1, profilesWritten); 

    } finally {
        writer.close(); // will this block run?
    }
 }
```

Now will the `finally()` block run just like a regular flow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding try catch finally with return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26658853/understanding-try-catch-finally-with-return)

Comment: Sorry, I understand the classic try, catch and finally flow. This question is different in the sense its related Junit test flow.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, the `finally` block will run.  Junit assertion errors are just normal exceptions so the usual java `try-catch-finally` pattern will work. You can even catch the `AssertionError` exception if you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Finally blocks are meant to be a container for code that fire no matter what. JUnit, or this example, is no different.