# finally fires post Assertion

Tags: c#

Rhetorical question (Answered here [Will the 'finally' block fire even after a Junit test throws an Assertion Error from with in 'try' block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847237/will-the-finally-block-fire-even-after-a-junit-test-throws-an-assertion-error)but) I'll ask anyway..
As Nunit is built in a similar fashion to Junit (In which the original question refereed to) I'm guessing that should be working in the same fashion, i.e, finally will fire post Assertion ?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see the results? :)

Comment: Hi @Gonzalo.- That's working for me but thouht that there may be additional implications that I'm not aware of..Especially now with Nunit3